# How to skip issue in Sonar Quality gates very first time

Tags: sonarqube

I am planing to integrate my project with SonarQube. My project code base is there for many years. After the very first integration I want to skip all the issues and code coverage. I only want the new code to follow the rules and report issues. Otherwise I want my project to get pass the gates with out considering the old code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the new ... issues conditions in your Quality Gate, i.e.

Metric                Operator          Error
New Blocker  Issues   is greater than   0
New Critical Issues   is greater than   0
New Major    Issues   is greater than   0

This way, the Quality Gate of the first scan will always be green.